# How to call method before using response data?

Tags: angular, angular5

I use routing and try to read get parameter `id`:

```
public classes: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['id']) {
        let a = getData(this.classes, params['id']);// Notice here
      }
    });
```

You can notice `this.classes` object. It is empty.

Below I have a method that fills `this.classes`:

```
 public loadClasses(): void {
    this.classService.getAllClasses()
      .subscribe(data => {
         this.classes = data;
    });
}
```

Problem is route works first therefore object `this.classes` is empty.

How to call first `loadClasses()` to load data for route: `let a = getData(this.classes, params['id']);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your data, you need the route parameter and the classes, this looks like a perfect case for [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) :

```
ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(this.route.params, this.classService.getAllClasses())
    .subscribe(([params, classes]) => {
        if (params['id']) {
            let a = getData(classes, params['id']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is like joinFork?

Comment: The `this.classService.getAllClasses` should return Observer type?

Comment: `joinFork` is another combination operator, depending on your case, you could have to use a different operator, have look at this page : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/. The `getAllClasses` should return an Observable, which seems to be already the case.

Comment: Can you edit your answer, cause problem is here: `.subscribe([params, classes] => {}` - unresolved variable classes, params

Comment: I forgot the parentheses, it should be fixed after the edit.

Comment: Are you sure that observables wait each others?

Comment: Yes absolutely, from the link in the answer : `Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value.`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do something like this:

```
    public classes: any;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.loadClasses().subscribe(() => getData());

    private getData(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          if (params['id']) {
            let a = getData(this.classes, params['id']);// Notice here
          }
        });
    }

     public loadClasses(): void {
        this.classService.getAllClasses()
          .subscribe(data => {
             this.classes = data;
        });
    }
```